# Calcule $\int _{C} \frac{z^2}{z-1} dz$, $|z|= 2$ and $\int _{C} \frac{e^{z}}{z^{2}} dz$, $|z | = 1$, where $C$ is a circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm studying the Cauchy’s integral theorem on circular contour. Is given in the study material that $z = re^{i\theta}$ and $dz = ire^{i\theta}d\theta$.
I don't know how to go about using $\mid z \mid$ in this problem. In both examples, I don't know how to solve the integrals to use the $\mid z \mid$ later.

In first case I try:

$$I = \int_{C} \frac{z^{2}}{z-1} dz$$
$$I = \int_{C} \frac{dz}{z-z_{0}} = 2\pi i f(z_{0})\text{.}$$
How
$$f(z) = z^{2}\text{ , }z_{0} = 1\text{,}$$
so
$$I = 2\pi if(z_{0}) = 2\pi i 1^{2} = 2\pi i $$

In second:

$$I = \int_{C} \frac{e^{z}}{z^{2}}dz$$
$$z^{2} = (z-0)^{2} = z^{2}-2 z (0)+0^{2}=z^{2}$$
Using the general formula,
$$I = \int_{C}\frac{e^{z}}{(z-0)^{2}} = 2\pi i \frac{f^{n-1}(a)}{(n-1)!}$$
How $f(z) = e^{z}$, $a=0$ and $f(a)=f(0)=e^{0}=1$,

$$I = \frac{2\pi i f^{(2-1)}(0)}{(2-1)!}=2\pi i \text{.}$$

I still don't know where to use the module. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For $R>0$, use $|z|=R$ as an anticlockwise contour, integrating with $z=Re^{i\theta}$ from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$.

Comment: But how to apply the Cauchy’s integral formula in this problem, and using $\mid z \mid = R$? Sorry for my unfamiliarity with this. I'm really starting my studiesand I'm already very confused about complex integrals involving |z|.

Comment: $|z|$ is used only in the definition of the contour. Could you provide us with the exact formulation of the Cauchy's integral theorem that was given to you. Then, we can help you with this question.